# I am having trouble returning prime factors of a number

Tags: python, computer-science, primes

I have the following method and when I run it I want to return a list of the prime factors for a number. For example, if I input 144, I want it to return [2,3]. I have the following method, but when I run it, there is infinite recursion.

```
def primeFactors(n):
    for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
        if n % i == 0:
            return list(set([i] + primeFactors(int(i))))
    return [n]
```

Comment: `math.ceil(math.sqrt(2)) + 1 == 3`, so you have no base case; every call results in at least one more recursive call.

Comment: Some style notes: 1. you should use a multiplication rather than a sqrt (this means giving up on `range` in favor of `itertools.count` and manual `break`), and 2. even if you insist on using recursion, rather than create and throw away sets, you should pass a set as an argument to accumulate into, and 3. what about repeated factors (normally I use a `dict` for factorization)

Answer (score 1):

You're passing the wrong value to the recursive call. If `i` divides `n`, then you want to add `i` to the set of prime factors of `n // i` (since `i * (n // i) == n` when `i` divides `n` evenly).

```
for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
    if n % i == 0:
        return [i] + primeFactors(n // i)
return [n]
```

Iterating to `n` (rather than the square root of `n`) may be faster in most cases, as the fact that `n` shrinks with each recursive call and only the last recursive call will actually iterate all the way to `n` means that iteration will
probably be faster than computing square roots.

If you only want the unique prime factors, use sets instead.

```
for i in range(2, math.ceil(math.sqrt(n)) + 1):
    if n % i == 0:
        return {i} | primeFactors(n // i)
return {n}
```

If you really want to speed things up, pass the last found factor as an argument and use it as your starting point:

```
def primefactors(n, x=2):
    for i in range(x, n):
        q, d = divmod(n, i)
        if d == 0:
            return {i} | primefactors(q, i)
    return {n}
```

As an exercise, try writing a version that extracts as many factors of 2 as possible; then you can iterate over only the odd factors 3, 5, ... instead of all integers greater than 2.

Comment: That doesn't seem to fully work. If I enter 144 it returns [2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3].

Comment: Oh, you only want the unique prime factors. I'll fix.

Comment: As an additional exercise, get a big table of prime numbers and only iterate over those.  It's not necessary to check non-primes.

Comment: @MarkRansom s/big/infinite :)